# 18.04 Touchpad only working in center area Lenovo P50

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

Strange problem with my touchpad, using a fresh install of 18.04.1 on a Lenovo thinkpad P50. I cannot use the left and right 1cm of the touchpad for starting a mouse movement. When I start the movement more by the center, the cursor keeps on moving also while using the outer edge of the touchpad.  Vertical scolling on the edge is disabled in gnome settings. Any idea how to get back the full touchpad dimensions?

Comment: How did you rule out a hardware issue? Does it work in other OS's(i.e. Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else has this issue...the fix was to manually install the synaptics driver. was not installed on ubuntu 18.04 during minimal installation option.

solved